# Is this recursion theoretic analogue of a criterion of weakly compact cardinal accurate?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

Jensen proved that, if V=L, and $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, then if for any stationary $A\subseteq \kappa$, the set $\{\alpha\mid A \text{ is stationary below }\alpha\}$ is stationary in $\kappa$, then $\kappa$ is weakly compact.

I heard that $\Pi_3$-reflecting ordinals are recursion theoretic analogues of weakly compact cardinals, and "stationary" corresponds to "$\Pi_2$-reflecting on".
So, is the following proposition true?

Let $\alpha$ be an admissible ordinal. Assume that for any $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ set $A\subseteq \alpha$, if $\alpha$ is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on $A$, then $\alpha$ is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on the ordinals that is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on $A$. Then $\alpha$ is $\Pi_3$-reflecting.

Comment: Since $\alpha<\kappa$ in the weakly compact formulation, shouldn't we have "if $\beta$ is $\Pi_2$-reflecting on $A$ then $\beta$ is ..." for ordinals $\beta<\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ itself?